# How to use one array to link to another one?

Tags: java, arrays

Hi guys basically im new to Java started in oct, im doing ComScience. I need help please with the following would be greatly appreciated.

NOTE: I have not really laid the code out yet so to speak i wanted to get the program to work first before structuring/comments etc . UULIB is name of the University librays.

OBJECTIVE: Find the NAME of students who have below AVERAGE mark.

This is the code i used below to try and find it but it skips the first [0] array number and gives me one name only.

```
import uulib.*;

public class Q3
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int class_number = Console.getInt("Enter how many students between 1-10");

        while (class_number < 1 || class_number > 10)
            class_number = Console.getInt("Enter how many students between 1-10");

        System.out.println("");

        String[] name = new String[class_number];
        int[] score = new int[name.length];

        for (int i=0; i<class_number; i=i+1)
        {
            name[i] = Console.getString("Enter Name");
            score[i] = Console.getInt("Enter score");

            if ( score[i] < average(score))
                System.out.print(name[i] + " ");
        }

        System.out.println(" ");
        System.out.println("Average mark = " + Num.format(average(score), 1 ));
        System.out.println("Lowset mark = " +lowset(score) );
        System.out.println("Highest mark = " +highestValue(score) );
        System.out.println("Name of students with highest mark =  " );
    }

    public static double average(int[] nums)
    {
        double total = 0;

        for (int i=0; i<nums.length; i=i+1)
        {
            total = total + nums[i];
        }
        return total / nums.length;
    }

    public static int lowset(int[] nums)
    {
        int minimum = nums[0]; //sets the first to be the smallest

        for (int i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) //goes through your array
        {
             if (nums[i] < minimum) //checks and replaces if necessary
             {
                 minimum = nums[i];   
             }
        }
        return minimum;
    }

    private static int highestValue(int[] numbers) 
    {
        int highest = numbers[0];
        for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) 
        {
            if (numbers[i] > highest) 
            {
                highest = numbers[i];
            }
        }
        return highest;
    }
}
```

Comment: _"I have not really laid the code out yet so to speak"_ Seriously - if you do not care, why should we?

Comment: Try to narrow your code down for everyone to read easier, and on a side note: people dont take kindly to homework questions that ask for direct answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should split your for-loop into two for-loops as you can't compute the average before having collected all scores:

```
for (int i=0; i<class_number; i=i+1) {
    name[i] = Console.getString("Enter Name");
    score[i] = Console.getInt("Enter score");
}
for (int i=0; i < class_number; i++) {
    if (score[i] < average(score))
        System.out.print(name[i] + " ");
}
```

Comment: You might want to compute the average just once, not on every iteration of the 2nd loop...

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your program needs to do 3 main things.

1. Collect input data (from the console)
2. Calculate averages (and anything else you need to calculate). Your code has highest and lowest, but your question text does not indicate that information is required.
3. Output results.

Here is a little code to help improve the organization of your code.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    collectInputData();
    calculate();
    outputResults();
}
```

**If you only remember one thing from the answer, remember this. DO NOT WAIT UNTIL YOUR CODE IS "WORKING" OR "GOOD" TO IMPROVE THE STRUCTURE OR COMMENTS!** You make your code good by improving the structure and comments.

Comment: thanks for that, yes i have to input data and 1.Average mark
2. Name(s) of student(s) below the average mark
3. Lowest mark
4. Highest mark
5. Name(s) of student(s) achieving highest mark

Answer (score 0):

In your first iteration (`i == 0`), `score[i] < average(score)` will evaluate to false, since actually `score[i] == average(score)`, that's why you don't get the first name printed.

However, your whole logic is flawed. You should first loop and ask the user to input the data, then calculate the arevage, and finally loop over the data again to determine which student has a grade lower than that calculated average.

Answer (score 0):

You are checking the first go around and that is obviously not going to be less than if it is the same. You should run through the if statement check after the array has been filled with all the grades and do the same for loop checking which grades are lower than the average.